# How to make java get a number and a new number and add them together

Tags: java

I Have been trying for some time now to get java to get and number and add a neww number to it but have had no luck.

```
package me.FL.PlayTime;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class PlayTimePlayer {
    long join = 0;
    Player player = null;

    private File f;
    public PlayTimePlayer(Player player){
        this.player = player;
        this.join = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    public void hold(){
        int seconds = (int) ((getMiliPlayTime() / (1000)) % 60);
        int minutes = (int) ((getMiliPlayTime() / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int hours   = (int) ((getMiliPlayTime() / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        int days    = (int) ((getMiliPlayTime() / (1000*60*60*24)) % 24);
    }

    public int getMiliPlayTime(){
        return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - join);
    }

    public int getSeconds(){
        return(int) (getMiliPlayTime() / 1000) % 60 ;
    }

    public int getMinutes(){
        return (int) ((getMiliPlayTime() / (1000*60)) % 60);    
    }

    public int getHours(){
        return (int) ((getMiliPlayTime() / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    }

    public int getDays(){
        return (int) ((getMiliPlayTime() / (1000*60*60*24)) % 24);
    }

    public String getTime(){
        String ptime = getDays() + ":" + getHours() + ":" + getMinutes() + ":" + getSeconds();
        System.out.println(ptime);
        return ptime;
    }

    public void save() throws IOException{
        if (Playtime.hascreatedfolder = false){
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("Fileloc"));
            while(s.hasNextLine()){
            String time = s.nextLine();
            String[] split = time.split(":");

                int days = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                int newday = getDays();
                int newTimeday = newday + days;

                int hours = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                int newhour = getHours();
                int newTimeHour = newhour + hours;

                int minutes = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
                int newminute = getMinutes();
                int newTimeminute = newminute + minutes;

                int seconds = Integer.parseInt(split[3]);
                int newsecond = getSeconds();
                int newTimesecond = newsecond + seconds;


                File f = new File("plugins/PlayerTime/");
                f.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(player.getDisplayName() + ".txt");
                if (f.exists());

                f.createNewFile();

                try {
                    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                    w.write(getTime());
                    w.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want it to get a time for example lets say it had 1:0:0 and i wanted to add 30 minutes i will like it to get 1:0:0 from a txt file and add 30 minutes from the server i should get 1:30:0 but i get 0:30:0 instead also it overwrited the oldnumbers txt file i dont want it to do this. please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Where is the offending code? What have you done to try to debug this? Any `System.out.println(...)` statements?

Comment: i know most of this works it creates the file and buts the number in but it over writes the old txt document and i want it to add to the old number not overwrite it

Comment: You really need to edit your question and provide a lot more detail as to what it is *exactly* that you're trying to do, what *exactly*, what  you've tried, all the details, because details *are* important.

Comment: If you want to append text to a text file, then this should be mentioned clearly in your question. A FileWriter will let you append to the file if you use the appropriate constructor and pass a `true` as the second constructor parameter.

Comment: What's with the link? Let's keep all pertinent information here, OK?

Comment: the link lets any one who will like to help edit the code i am sorry that my question is unclear.

Comment: In my experience that's not how it works here, and this goes against the general philosophy of this site. We are glad to offer suggestions, but it is ultimately *your* responsibility to update your code. Again, I suggest that you clarify and update your question as much as possible.

Comment: I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels - this question will not be useful to anyone with a similar problem in future (not that I'm really sure what exactly the problem is) unless you provide more detail, narrow down the problem, and keep the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from looking at your code and reading your brief description what exactly you're trying to achieve, so here are a few notes that might help you to get going:

- You have an incorrect boolean condition `hascreatedfolder = false`, I think you want to use `==` unless it's *meant* to be an assignment?
- you have no validation but the code seems to be expecting the format "days:hours:minutes:seconds" with four colon-separated values, whereas from your description you seem to have three ("hours:minutes:seconds").
- You have several unnecessary casts from int to int (not a problem per se, just being pedantic)
- unused instance variable File f (again just being pedantic)

I'd recommend you step through your code with a debugger and see where it's doing something different from what you're expecting.

Edit: As another general tip for what I think you're trying to do, have a look at [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and use that to add times/dates.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that here:

```
try {
    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    w.write(getTime());
    w.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You're only writing the new times in; you've not passed your newTimeincrements anywhere or done anything with them. if you were to change it to, say, `w.write(newTimeday + ":" + newTimehour + ":" + newTimeminute + ":" + newTimesecond);` you would be writing your new values in. If there's a ClassCastException there, you can also use something like

```
w.write(String.valueOf(newTimeday) + ":" + String.valueOf(newTimehour) + ":" + String.valueOf(newTimeminute) + ":" + String.valueOf(newTimesecond));
```

I don't use Buffered writers, so I don't know if it'll simply accept the integers in the string without conversion. Second option is just in case it doesn't.